# How do I store values from a single column into a single variable in oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections, plsql-package

The below is my code:

```
SELECT
      /*+ parallel (sales 8) */     
      COUNT(1)
    INTO v_datacount_actualtable
    FROM sales
    WHERE processingunitseq=38
    AND (compensationdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(v_startdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(v_enddate,'DD-MON-YYYY')
    OR eventtypeseq IN
      (SELECT EVENTTYPESEQ FROM EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS
      ));
```

`SELECT EVENTTYPESEQ FROM EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS` will return 4 values. So I cannot do a simple SELECT INTO.

I want to store the result of `SELECT EVENTTYPESEQ FROM EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS` into a variable and make the code something like below, so that the subquery is not executed each time.

```
SELECT
      /*+ parallel (sales 8) */     
      COUNT(1)
    INTO v_datacount_actualtable
    FROM sales
    WHERE processingunitseq=38
    AND (compensationdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(v_startdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(v_enddate,'DD-MON-YYYY')
    OR eventtypeseq = v_frseventpeseqs );
```

`SELECT EVENTTYPESEQ FROM EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS` returns four values:

```
1,
2,
3,
4,
```

I do not want to hardcode these values in the code as it is a bad practice. Need it in a variable like v_frseventypeseqs.

How can I do that - array/ collection/records/bulk collect into?

Comment: Yes a collection with `bulk select into` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Create type if it isn't exists

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE t_number1 AS TABLE OF NUMBER(8,0)
```

it's array of number

and using in PL/SQL

```
declare
v_frseventpeseqs t_number1;
begin
    SELECT EVENTTYPESEQ bulk collect 
    into v_frseventpeseqs 
    FROM EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS;

    for i in (select t.column_value id from table(v_frseventpeseqs) t)
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(i.id );
    end loop;

end;
```

only using statement in (select t.column_value
from table(v_frseventpeseqs) t)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WITH clause. The advantage is that repeated references to a subquery may be more efficient as the data is easily retrieved from a temporary table, rather than being requeried by each reference.

```
WITH eventtypeseq_query AS 
     (SELECT EVENTTYPESEQ 
      FROM EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS)
SELECT
       /*+ parallel (sales 8) */   
       COUNT(1)
INTO v_datacount_actualtable
FROM sales
WHERE processingunitseq=38
  AND (compensationdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(v_startdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(v_enddate,'DD-MON-YYYY')
        OR eventtypeseq IN eventtypeseq_query);
```

You can find more information here:
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause

Answer (score 0):

Since

```
SELECT EVENTTYPESEQ FROM EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS
```

is not correlated you don't need any "optimization" here - Oracle will run this subquery only once.

Answer (score 0):

Using `EXISTS` is always better in terms of performance as compared to using `IN`.
Also, if you are writing this query to run regularly in LIVE environment, it is suggested not to use HINTs like `/*+ parallel */`. HINTs should be used only for ad-hoc queries.

I have re-written your query below using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT
    /*+ parallel (sales 8) */     
    COUNT(1)
    INTO v_datacount_actualtable
    FROM sales sl
    WHERE processingunitseq=38
    AND (compensationdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(v_startdate,'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE(v_enddate,'DD-MON-YYYY')
    OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 from EPS_FRS_PAYMENTS efp where s.eventtypeseq = efp.eventtypeseq);
```